# How to access HTML sublist

Tags: jquery, html

So i have this structure (it's an example), first list is to list clients, second tu show/hide documents from each client:

```
<ul class="first_ul">
     <li class="first_li">
          <span>ClientName</span>
          <ul class="sub_ul">
                <li class="sub_li">
                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                    <span>Document 1</span>
                    <i class="icon-circle" style="color:#11C011"></i>
                </li>
          </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Followed by a jquery onclick which hide/show that sublist.

```
     $(".first_ul li").on("click", function(){   
         var child = $(this).children('.sub_ul');
         child.slideToggle(); //toggle current one
     });
```

The problem i have is that i cannot access that sublist, because everytime i try to click on that checkbox, that sublist hides, when i press F12 to see what happen, i can only select li from the first list.

Is there any way to solve this problem for example by saying that the sublist is more important than the first list, to come up or i don't know. Thanks!

Comment: not getting what exactly you want to achieve after click on first_ul, can you elaborate more on it

Comment: Yes my bad, that first list is to show a list of clients, and on each client it has a sublist of documents, this showed here is just an example of the structure.

Comment: @Martinez Please explain what result do you expect?

Comment: @Martinez, please check the answer i have provided with `e.stopPropagation`

Comment: @Pedram What i want to do is just show/hide that sublist when i click on the first li, not when i click on the sublist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `e.stopPropagation` inside click handler of parent li as shown below, this will stop click event propagation from child to parent element which is causing to trigger click event of parent li element i.e. first_li. Also, added if condition to check the clicked element is li or its child element.

Also, use `find()` to get all child element with class `sub_ul`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".first_ul li").on("click", function(e){   
         e.stopPropagation();
         // return if parent not clicked
          if (e.target !== this)
             return;
         var child = $(this).find('.sub_ul');
         child.slideToggle();
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="first_ul">
     <li class="first_li">
          <ul class="sub_ul">
                <li class="sub_li">
                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                    <span>Sub Menu 1</span>
                    <i class="icon-circle" style="color:#11C011"></i>
                </li>
          </ul>
     </li>
      <li class="first_li">
          <ul class="sub_ul">
                <li class="sub_li">
                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                    <span>Sub Menu 2</span>
                    <i class="icon-circle" style="color:#11C011"></i>
                </li>
          </ul>
     </li>
      <li class="first_li">
          <ul class="sub_ul">
                <li class="sub_li">
                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                    <span>Sub Menu 3</span>
                    <i class="icon-circle" style="color:#11C011"></i>
                </li>
          </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It does the same to me, the problem is that the sublist is surrounded by that first li, so when i try to click on the sublist, it clicks the li. When i inspect, i cannot see the sublist, it just marks me the first li, that's why it always show/hide the sublist even if i click on the checkbox.

Comment: ok ... i have added if condition to check if parent is clicked or not and then only show/hide child otherwise return.. please check my updated answer and let me know if that works or not

Comment: Nothing mate, exactly the same, now if i click on the clientName it doesn't show/hide sublist, but when i click anything else, sublist included it'll do the toggle thing. It still marks the sublist as this first li when i inspect the element, i don't know if it's for that.

Comment: code snippet is working for me where i can show / hide sub_ul only on click of first_li, not sure why it is not working for you. Can you recreate this on code snippet or jsfiddle so that i can take a look at it

Comment: I found it! That sub-ul css had that pointer-events:none, i don't know why, not my program just fixing it. Thanks friends!

Answer (score 0):

Use **[e.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)** on `.sub_ul` or where you want to stop what under `click` event *!*

```js
$(".first_ul li").on("click", function() {
  var child = $(this).children('.sub_ul');
  child.slideToggle();
});

$('.sub_ul').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.first_li {
  background: lightgray;
}

.sub_ul {
  background: gray
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="first_ul">
  <li class="first_li">
    <span>ClientName</span>
    <ul class="sub_ul">
      <li class="sub_li">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>Document 1</span>
        <i class="icon-circle" style="color:#11C011"></i>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't get it man, your example works perfectly, but not mine when i inspect your example, i can arrive to your sublist i can mark that "Document 1", but not in my case, when i inspect when sublist is open, and i try to access to it, it always mark that first li "ClientName".

Comment: @Martinez Are you you cleared cache or there is no other script to conflict? or etc.

Comment: I found it! That sub-ul css had that pointer-events:none, i don't know why, not my program just fixing it. Thanks friends!